# D3.js pinch zoom and drag on an orthographic map

Tags: d3.js, maps, zooming, drag, orthographic

I'm having issues trying to get both drag and zoom events working on touch devices. One thing I'm not certain of is whether it is correct to have two calls on one selection.

With the current code (just an excerpt) drag works both on mobile and desktop (Safari and Chrome), however, whereas zoom using wheel works on desktop, double tapping or pinching does not have any effect on mobile.

Thanks in advance for any help given!

```
this.projection = d3.geoOrthographic()
    .translate([this.width / 2, this.height / 2])
    .scale(this.defaultScale)
    .rotate(this.rotate)
    .center(this.center)
    .clipAngle(90)

this.path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(this.projection)

this.zoomEvent = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 100])
    .on("zoom", (k) => {
        let scale = (d3.event.transform.k > this.lastScale)
            ? this.projection.scale() + (d3.event.transform.k * 10)
            : this.projection.scale() - (d3.event.transform.k * 10) 

        this.projection.scale( scale );
        this.redraw();

        this.currentScale = this.projection.scale();
        this.lastScale = d3.event.transform.k;
    });

this.dragEvent = d3.drag()
    .subject((d)=> {
        let r = this.projection.rotate(); 
        return {
            x: r[0] / this.sens, 
            y: -r[1] / this.sens
        };
    })
    .on("drag",() => {
        this.projection.rotate([d3.event.x * this.sens, -d3.event.y * 
        this.sens, this.projection.rotate()[2] ]);
        this.redraw();
    })
})

 this.svg = d3.select("#map-area").append("svg")
     .attr("id", "map")
     .attr("width", this.width)
     .attr("height", this.height)
     .append('g')
     .call(this.dragEvent)
     .call(this.zoomEvent)
```

Comment: Hey Sheldon! Welcome to StackOverflow. This is an interesting question, but you've only provided about half the code necessary to replicate the bug. Please provide enough code for a minimum replicable example!